# Which Linux distro should I use for Apache, mod_wsgi, Python, Django, PostgreSQL deployment?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, python, deployment, django

Currently we are running CentOS for our production servers. Wer're deploying Django projects with Apache 2.2, mod_wsgi and PostgreSQL.

We are in the process of making Python 2.5 the default version. However, this version is not in the standard CentOS repositories. I have more knowledge of Debian/ubuntu than CentOS. What would be a better distro choice for this requirements and why?

Comment: david and jldugger gave the answers i would have so i'll just upvote them both rather than give the same answer again.  it's good advice.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu is a suitable choice. The Django team apparently uses it. For starters, Ubuntu has old and new versions of python. 2.5 is available in Hardy LTS, and 2.6 is in the newest stable release.

Secondly, django itself is available in the repositories, as `python-django`. This might seem pointless as people generally deploy Django from SVN, but it does mean there's a place to report integration problems and documented dependencies and suggestions.

Comment: +1 for Ubuntu. Also keep in mind that there is an enormous amount of information available in terms of how to to's and tutorials to set up these sorts of things on Ubuntu. I found this lacking with other distrubutions.

Answer (score 6):

The best distribution for pretty much any job is the one you are most familiar with. You want to be dealing with deploying the application you aren't familiar with; you don't want to be fighting with a different distribution too.